# HID compliant device will not enumerate using chrome.hid API on ChromeOS

Tags: javascript, usb, google-chrome-app, hid, google-chrome-os

Using a USB HID sensor I can only seem to enumerate the device with the [`chrome.usb` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) on ChromeOS.

On OS X I can enumerate with the [`chrome.hid` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid) with no problem.

What could be the reasons for HID devices not being identified as such on ChromeOS?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you running in the ChromeOS?

Comment: @Rivero I've tried versions 38-40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible the device is blacklisted by the Linux HID driver. If you can put your Chrome OS device in developer mode or connect the device to a Linux computer you can check the kernel log  to see how the device is recognized. If all is well then there should be a /dev/hidraw node created for the device.

Can you tell me what the device vendor and product IDs are?

Comment: Thanks for the response Reilly. The device does identify as a HID device but it loads a generic driver. I'll need to check if I can post the vid/pid publicly.

Comment: Hi Reilly, The vendorId is 08f7(2295) and the productId is 2. We have other productIds but that's the one we're trying to test with. Thanks again

Comment: By "a generic driver" do you mean it is only enumerated as a USB device (no function driver loaded for the HID interface), that only the hid-generic driver is loaded, with no /dev/hidraw<N> device not created, or that a generic input driver attaches to the device? Please add a (redacted if necessary) snippet of the kernel log from when the device is connected to your question.

Comment: See the post from Jennifer above. The device is currently blacklisted.

Comment: Reilly, the device does appear to be blacklisted. I've opened another question here on SO to address this since this question is answered. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608071/what-is-the-process-for-getting-a-hid-compliant-usb-device-removed-from-chromeos