# What is the process for getting a HID compliant USB device removed from ChromeOS blacklist?

Tags: usb, google-chrome-app, hid, google-chrome-os

Attempting to use the chrome.hid API for a Chrome Packaged App we ran into an issue where our USB devices are in the ignore/blacklist.

What is the process for ChromeOS to get all of our devices removed from the blacklist? See this post for reference: [HID compliant device will not enumerate using chrome.hid API on ChromeOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557114/hid-compliant-device-will-not-enumerate-using-chrome-hid-api-on-chromeos)

Comment: You should mention in your question where the black list is so people have a chance of figuring out where it came from and who maintains it.  Apparently, according to a deleted "answer" in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557114/hid-compliant-device-will-not-enumerate-using-chrome-hid-api-on-chromeos), the blacklist is in `hid-core.c` which I assume is part of the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a Chrome OS specific problem. This device is in the Linux kernel's [hid_ignore_list](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.18/drivers/hid/hid-core.c#L2357) because it [doesn't implement the HID protocol correctly](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/4871d3be13ea2b33edc9ba6fbcc30fc047087be7). Given that the device is blacklisted and so not claimed by the HID driver you should be able to open it using the chrome.usb API.